# PHP loadHTML getting HTML5 data attributes

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I'm loading an HTML string that may have arbitrary custom HTML5 'data-' attributes such as

```
<div data-test='foo'></div>
```

I can access those attributes if I know the exact name like:

```
echo $element->getAttribute('data-test');
```

which will find and print the value of the attribute.
HOWEVER, if I try to loop through all attributes:

```
foreach($element->attributes as $att){
    echo $att->value'
}
```

it does not find the custom 'data-' attributes. That is a problem, as I'm trying to remove unwanted 'data-' attributes without knowing all of the possible names in advance.

Comment: What version of libxml2 you have on your system? With `2.8.0` it is working

Comment: Did you finally Dong! about it?