# Pass PHP variables without using href in Bootstrap tabs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to send PHP variables using the `<a>` tag and the data attribute on the same PHP page using the Bootstrap tabs:

HTML (Bootstrap tab option):

```
<a style='padding:20px;' href='#tab_e' data-page='$page' class='passrss' data-rssid='$rssid' data-toggle='tab'>Test</a>
```

PHP (stored in #tab_e tab):

```
$rsspassedid = GET $rssid from the a tag (data-rssid)
```

I'd like to get the value stored in data-rssid on click and pass it to a variable further down in the same PHP file so that when the tab is opened using `#tab_e`, the mySQL statement will run based on the value provided in $rssid and display the results of the query. I'm not sure if any jQuery/AJAX would be required for this but is it possible to get data stored in the data attribute of the `<a>` tag in PHP?

### UPDATE

I've tried storing the variables in the pagination links but still no luck, here's the XHR object I created:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.passrss').click(function () {
        $('span.pass-tabe').load('tabe.php?rssid=' + $(this).data('rssid') + '&page=' + $(this).data('page'));
    });

    }); 
</script>
```

Tabe passes the variables stored in the a tag to a seperate php file (`tabe.php`) which then loads into the browser using `<span class="pass-tabe"></span>`, as for pagination - the links are stored in the tabe.php file but they refer back to the main php file hence pagination fails to work e.g.

```
originalphpfile.php?page=$page&rssid=$rssidpassed&pageurl=$x#tab_e
```

NOTE: `$rssidpassed` is stored in `tabe.php` which it gets from the XHR object e.g.

```
$_GET['rssid']
```

### UPDATE 2

I've added the code for pagination below where I'm having the issue at the moment which is stored in tabe.php:

```
$perpage = 10;
$pageurl = (isset($_GET['pageurl'])) ? (int)$_GET['pageurl'] : 1;
$start = ($pageurl - 1) * $perpage;

$pagequery = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('topic_id') FROM topic WHERE cat_id='$page' AND topic.users_id = '$rssid'");
$pagination = ceil(mysql_result($pagequery, 0) / $perpage);

//query goes here

//pagination numbers
if($pagination >= 1){
    echo "<div style='text-align:center;'><ul class='pagination'>";
    for($x=1; $x<=$pagination; $x++){
    echo ($x == $pageurl) ? "<li class='active'><a href='originalphpfile.php?page=$page&pageurl=$x#tab_e'>$x</a></li>":"<li><a href='originalphpfile.php?page=$page&pageurl=$x#tab_e'>$x</a></li>"; 
    }
    echo "</ul></div>";
}
```

When I click on pagination links, it doesn't load the second, third, etc set of results as it returns to the originalphpfile.php

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: You would need to use Ajax for this functionality to occur. Any click event would suggest that you've sent the HTML/CSS/JS to the client. Because the client would need to communicate again with your server to get the results of the MySQL query, you'd need a new request to do so.

In essence, there is no direct way to pass php to the mysql query. You'd render it as an attribute value, retrieve it with jQuery, and fire it back to the server.

Comment: I'm not too sure how to go about this, I've created a XHR object by sending the data attributes to an external PHP file and loading it back into #tab_e. Although this works, it doesn't work with pagination as the tabbed content is being sent to an external PHP file. I'm not sure if theres a way to store the data attribute of rssid in AJAX and fire it back as a value to be stored in the same PHP file

Comment: You need to understand the request/response cycle. Most web sites are set up this way and thusly do not have state. State is "expensive." The client needs to store this information and format the request as such that PHP just reads it and responds. If you want pagination, store these variables on the client and send them with the request that built the PHP response.

Comment: That's hard to read, can you update your original post with that in the codeblocks? Update: Can you also include your MySQL query? Update2: Please put your jQuery, PHP, and MySQL in an ### Update ### block in your original post so I can help you out.

Comment: I see `$(this).data('page')` but I don't see `... data-page="??"...` anywhere. On what element is the `data-page` attribute located?

Comment: Updated original, its part of the <a> tag

Comment: Okay, next, looking at your "tabe.php" file, where do you expect to get the `$_GET['pageurl']` variable? I don't see it in your jQuery `.load` function, first argument: `'tabe.php?rssid=' + $(this).data('rssid') + '&page=' + $(this).data('page')`.

Comment: $_GET['pageurl'] is sent when click on the pagination links e.g. originalphpfile.php?page=$page&pageurl=$x#tab_e
I haven't included pageurl in the .data function but it still loads tabe.php, its just when I click on <a href='originalphpfile.php?page=$page&pageurl=$x#tab_e'>$x</a></li> it fails to load the next set of results in the original php - I think the issue is that it's not calling the function again hence the span tag doesn't re-load into the page, I've tried calling the class on the pagination links but it doesn't work

Comment: Any ideas for a solution? @bloodyKnuckles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved, I echoed out the AJAX into the tabe php file and changed the pagination HTML links:

tabe.php pagination link:

```
<a href='#tab_e' class='passrssurl' data-rssid='$rsspassedid' data-url='$x' data-page='$page' data-toggle='tab'>
```

tabe.php echo AJAX:

```
echo "<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.passrssurl').click(function () {
    $('span.pass-tabe').load('tabe.php?rssid=' + $(this).data('rssid') + '&page=' + $(this).data('page') + '&pageurl=' + $(this).data('url'));
    });

}); 
</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and turn this into an answer because our comment blocks are getting long.

In your PHP template, to turn PHP into something useful you're going to need to do something like this:

```
// file1.php
// notice <?= ?> is quick echo, the same as <? echo $rssid; ?>
<a style='padding:20px;' href='#tab_e' data-rssid='<?= $rssid ?>' data-toggle='tab'>Test</a>
```

In your javascript, the reason you're getting $rssid is because you're not echoing the value, I think, according to the post.

```
// file2.php
$page = array_key_exists($_GET,'page') && is_numeric( $_GET['page'] ) ? $_GET['page'] : 1
// do query i.e select * from x offset $page * $per_page limit $per_page

// do stuff with your pagination in a loop defining an index $number
<a class="pagination" onclick="getPage(<?= $number ?>)"><?= $number; ?></a>
```

Then in jquery:

```
// Call this when they click the tab
var id;
function setId(id){
   id = id;
   getPage(1);
}

// call this when they click the pagination
function getPage(number){
   $('span.pass-tabe').load('tabe.php?rssid=' + $id + '&page=' +number )
}
```

Please massage the example code, it seems as if you're doing something complex and it's hard to necessarily grasp your exact use case precisely.

Comment: Ok, to put it as simple as possible, the pagination works fine as in sending variables to the web browser URL, but the issue is that the pagination links refer back to page 1 rather than carrying out the load function again to tabe.php. For example, when I click 2 on the pagination, it just loads page 1 (the original PHP) with the first XHR send rather than loading the second set of results. All pagination links are stored in the XHR object php file tabe.

Comment: I've tried using $element->getAttribute('data-rssid') but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to do this, but I can't seem to get it to work... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334995/php-loadhtml-getting-html5-data-attributes

Comment: Because you're not using the pagination in your SQL.

Comment: It's in the SQL, it works fine if I load it normally, it's just when it's in the XHR, the '<span>' tag doesn't load again when you click on a pagination link as theres no load function in the pagination url links to span.pass-tabe

Comment: If you use my example, the pagination links call a function that should set the page properly. If you're not getting the expected data back then it's a query issue. getPage($num) should work if you're pagination is correct.

Comment: It doesn't work, I've updated the pagination snippet I've used if the original

Comment: I believe the issue is occuring with the <span> tag, as it fails to re-load the code in tabe when you click the pagination links which refer back to the original php, I've tried repeating the same load function in the original php with a seperate class that's also applied to the pagination links but it doesn't work - an alternative idea is to not use .load, but an AJAX get function and then calling the tabe using the include function in the original php rather than a span tag - not to sure how to write an AJAX get function though to pass the variables to tabe